# Angular render string based on expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a method to that returns an integer value, `{{Cart.totalItems()}}`.  This works fine.  I wanted to know if it is possible to have this expression print a string based on the result of this method call.  For example:

> print "X" if the value returned is greater than 0, or "Y" otherwise.

Is this possible in the expression itself (for example by using a filter) or do I need to roll an Angular function to do this?  I've used *similar* techniques done in the expression specified in an `ng-show`directive, for example:

```
{true:'false',false:'true'}[ngTransaction.$state.shippingNameSameAsCustomerName]
```

However, I cannot seem to nail the syntax for this in view.  Is it possible to render a string conditionally based on the output of a function call in an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [JavaScript ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside an interpolated template:

```
{{ Cart.totalItems() > 123 ? 'Happy' : 'Sad' }}
```

The above code will print `Happy` if the value returned by `Cart.totalItems()` is greater than `123`, `Sad` otherwise.